# how to convert tokenModel.ExpiresIn into seconds

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, access-token, asp.net-core-3.1

I have `ExpiresOn` for Azure AD token which is a type of `DateTimeOffset`. My model class is below,

```
public class AadToken
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ExpiresIn { get; set; }
}
```

and a method returns the above model like below,

```
return new AadToken { ExpiresIn = accessToken.ExpiresOn, Value = accessToken.Token };
```

Now I need to convert it into seconds and set like below,

```
//tokenModel.ExpiresIn needs to convert in sec.

entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenModel.ExpiresIn);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's like asking how many seconds there are in `2021-08-27 20:10:03`. A date is an instant in time, not a duration, so the question has no answer.

You can calculate how many seconds are between two dates, eg now and the target date, eg `tokenModel.ExpiresIn - DateTimeOffset.Now`. This returns a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0) class with the duration. You can use the [TotalSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalseconds?view=net-5.0) property to get the duration in seconds

```
var expSpan=(tokenModel.ExpiresIn - DateTimeOffset.Now);
entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = expSpan.TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: aah. ok. Thanks much and appreciate @Panagiotis Kanavos